# How integrate Sofort payment method in Shopify for Asian Country?

Tags: stripe-payments, shopify, shopify-app, klarna

I am new in Shopify development and I am researching on integrating any of Sofort, Klarna or Ideal payment system integration with Shopify store. The store business address is Malaysia but the store wants to sale in European countries.

I am researching on this issue but I am not sure still how to do it. Or is it even possible. Can we use Stripe for this purpose?

Comment: All of these payment gateways have some countries-specific working and you also need to check with payment gateway serves into your country and choose one which is available. yes, the stripe is available in Malaysia, but in Shopify, you can use it through Shopify payments, not directly. because Shopify process the payments its using Stripe.

Comment: @Onkar ok then what if i want to sale the products in europe and want to offer the payment gateways available in eruope?

Comment: I think payment gateways support the Shopify addresses not the area you want to sell, you need to choose the universal CC process or PAYPAL that accepts payment, I am not sure but local famous payment processors are not available in this case.

Comment: You should contact Shopify support for help with configuring this if their docs are not providing the information you need to get started.
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/payments/shopify-payments/local-payment-methods/sofort#activate-sofort

Comment: You can see the payment methods you can activate at https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/payment_methods. The payment methods you can activate vary depending on your Stripe merchant account country. If these payment methods are not available in your Stripe account, you can set up your company in US with Stripe Atlas https://atlas.stripe.com/invite/8ykr8gmr and accept these payment methods. If you want to accept these payment methods via Stripe in your Shopify store, take a look at the "Stripe indirect integration for Shopify - All in One" solution https://techtolia.com/ShopifyStripe/